Flutter app exited, due to Impeller renderer ImpellerValidationBreak, with excessive logs of: I/MESA exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image
I use Mac.
I just upgraded, to Flutter 3.27.1.
I run myproject on android emulator, through VSCode start debugging button in main.dart
When the debugging starts, the app builds successfully, but exited after some minutes of loggings!
then I run the project through the following terminal command:
flutter run --no-enable-impeller

Which runs successfully without exiting the app, but I still want to solve the errors to run through VSCode start debugging button. and I don't want to ignore the impeller, or adding
.vscode/launch.json  file to my project.
Appreciate any possible direct solution for that...
The debugConsole logs: (was 4371 lines, but I delete some duplicates due to body characters limit)
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
I/flutter (12846): [IMPORTANT:flutter/shell/platform/android/android_context_vk_impeller.cc(60)] Using the Impeller rendering backend (Vulkan).
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:55932/32IKaxmdpPY=/ws
Connected to the VM Service.
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 145
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 154
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(12846): sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=false callback=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity$1@891be9d
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 159
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 162
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 163
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 167
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 168
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 169
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 170
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 166
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 154
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 159
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 162
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 163
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 167
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 168
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 169
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 170
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 166
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 154
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 159
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 162
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 163
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 167
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 145
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 169
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 170
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 168
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 166
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 159
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 171
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 162
D/ProfileInstaller(12846): Installing profile for com.example.myproject
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 166
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 170
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 162
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 164
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 165
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352987c90 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a15
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 167
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352986790 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a16
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 161
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb4000073529861d0 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a17
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 177
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007352978890 hos timage handle 0x7000600000a18
I/MESA    (12846): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 163
E/flutter (12846): [ERROR:flutter/impeller/renderer/backend/vulkan/descriptor_pool_vk.cc(116)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Could not allocate descriptor sets: ErrorOutOfPoolMemory
E/flutter (12846): [ERROR:flutter/impeller/renderer/backend/vulkan/descriptor_pool_vk.cc(116)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Could not allocate descriptor sets: ErrorOutOfPoolMemory
E/flutter (12846): [ERROR:flutter/impeller/renderer/backend/vulkan/descriptor_pool_vk.cc(116)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Could not allocate descriptor sets: ErrorOutOfPoolMemory
E/flutter (12846): [ERROR:flutter/impeller/renderer/backend/vulkan/descriptor_pool_vk.cc(116)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Could not allocate descriptor sets: ErrorOutOfPoolMemory
E/flutter (12846): [ERROR:flutter/impeller/renderer/backend/vulkan/descriptor_pool_vk.cc(116)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Could not allocate descriptor sets: ErrorOutOfPoolMemory
E/flutter (12846): [ERROR:flutter/impeller/renderer/backend/vulkan/descriptor_pool_vk.cc(116)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Could not allocate descriptor sets: ErrorOutOfPoolMemory
F/libc    (12846): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8cb4000000630011 in tid 12939 (1.raster), pid 12846 (example.myproject)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emu64a:15/AE3A.240806.005/12228598:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2024-12-24 23:56:26.957394349+0300
Process uptime: 149s
Cmdline: com.example.myproject
pid: 12846, tid: 12939, name: 1.raster  >>> com.example.myproject <<<
uid: 10207
tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001 (PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE)
pac_enabled_keys: 000000000000000f (PR_PAC_APIAKEY, PR_PAC_APIBKEY, PR_PAC_APDAKEY, PR_PAC_APDBKEY)
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8cb4000000630011
    x0  b400007322a64410  x1  b4000072129a4290  x2  0000000000000020  x3  0000000000000000
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  b4000071b299a430  x6  b4000073529dc6d0  x7  b4000073529bcaea
    x8  0000000000000044  x9  0000000000000006  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000000018  x13 8e38e38e38e38e39  x14 0000000000000048  x15 0000000000000002
    x16 0000000000000000  x17 8cb4000000630011  x18 00000070c849c000  x19 0000000000000001
    x20 b400007322a643d0  x21 0000000000000000  x22 b400007322a64410  x23 0000000000000010
    x24 b4000071b297acc0  x25 b400007222917850  x26 b400007212a078c0  x27 b400007222917860
    x28 00000070ce00aa80  x29 00000070ce0088a0
    lr  00000071288cba2c  sp  00000070ce0088a0  pc  0000007128883db4  pst 0000000060001000
39 total frames
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000007fdb4  /vendor/lib64/hw/vulkan.ranchu.so (gfxstream::vk::doEmulatedDescriptorWrite(VkWriteDescriptorSet const*, gfxstream::vk::ReifiedDescriptorSet*)+308) (BuildId: 97175a87159c1611c26e784dab8676ef)
      #01 pc 00000000000c7a28  /vendor/lib64/hw/vulkan.ranchu.so (gfxstream::vk::ResourceTracker::on_vkUpdateDescriptorSets(void*, VkDevice_T*, unsigned int, VkWriteDescriptorSet const*, unsigned int, VkCopyDescriptorSet const*)+340) (BuildId: 97175a87159c1611c26e784dab8676ef)
      #02 pc 000000000007df10  /vendor/lib64/hw/vulkan.ranchu.so (gfxstream_vk_UpdateDescriptorSets+716) (BuildId: 97175a87159c1611c26e784dab8676ef)
      #03 pc 00000000020c144c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #04 pc 0000000002080f2c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #05 pc 00000000020809d8  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #06 pc 0000000002086bac  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #07 pc 00000000020547b4  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #08 pc 000000000205300c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #09 pc 00000000020541ac  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #10 pc 0000000002059888  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #11 pc 0000000001d1228c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #12 pc 000000000205a144  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #13 pc 0000000001d12f24  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #14 pc 0000000001d1228c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #15 pc 0000000001d12738  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #16 pc 000000000205b0e4  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #17 pc 0000000002151450  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #18 pc 0000000001fd73ac  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #19 pc 0000000001fd728c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #20 pc 0000000001fd7314  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #21 pc 00000000020dc93c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #22 pc 00000000020dc3f0  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #23 pc 00000000020db28c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #24 pc 00000000020dbc60  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #25 pc 00000000020dd834  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #26 pc 00000000020db6fc  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #27 pc 00000000020db494  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #28 pc 00000000020e9c9c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #29 pc 0000000001cacfe8  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #30 pc 0000000001cb2a28  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #31 pc 0000000000013498  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+1520) (BuildId: eb16d925d301dcbe28e761592a8de52d)
      #32 pc 000000000001f0c0  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100) (BuildId: 4af7b1a4467bbba7d937b317a37d0e9b)
      #33 pc 0000000001cb29b0  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #34 pc 0000000001cacf34  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #35 pc 0000000001cb0c94  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #36 pc 0000000001cb0b2c  /data/app/~~YquSxpd-0ji1mMj_tjLaAg==/com.example.myproject-aDNp7FOk-2LGRaXQ8ZJLeA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b0c8ea18145e86f27eccbf0956cff58f847fee5b)
      #37 pc 000000000006c354  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+196) (BuildId: 1b9fecf834d610f77e641f026ca7269b)
      #38 pc 000000000005efc4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 1b9fecf834d610f77e641f026ca7269b)
Lost connection to device.

Exited.


I tried the followings:

how can I solve "Using the Impeller rendering backend." error?
Android Godot integration: limit log
Excessive Logging After Flutter SDK Update: exportSyncFdForQSRILocked and sendCancelIfRunning Messages

